# How to get a value of selected row by didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Table View Controller and every cell contain user information: name, photo, and age.

I want when I select user from Table View display all information of user in another view by his id, but he's id does not exist inside the cell, it's saved in a server, I doesn't load id's when load all user in a table, because I don't need it in this time, I just have name, photo, and age, what I can do?

I've thought about that to declare a variable inside the cell that represent the id, without print this variable just to load id from server, like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let student = Student.students[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ourCell",    forIndexPath: indexPath) as? MyCellTableViewCell {

        var x = loadInfo.id // here id declare variable

    return cell
    }
```

And after then use function `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` to know who user I selected, but in this way I just have cell indexPath in function `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()`, Can I access through indexPath to my variable that contains user id? Or is any better way to do that?

Comment: Never – unless you have absolutely no choice – use table view cells (the view) to share data, use always the data source array (the model).

Comment: @vadian do you mean i have declare variable in cell "view" and then access to it? how i can access to this var in didSelectRowAtIndexPath()

Comment: Put all your required data in the `students` array and get it from there since you have the index path.

Comment: You may want to look at the oft-used Delegation pattern in Swift, which can be found on this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Comment: you need to fall back to your _model_ after your have the selected row id and grab the details from there for your new view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're giving yourself a bigger headache by not retrieving the id's from the server. If you retrieve the Id's with the user information, and store it in an array of students; then whenever a cell is selected in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, You can simply retrieve the info like this in the viewcontroller:

```
let studentInfo = Student.students[indexPath.row]
var studentId = studentInfo.id()
```

Comment: Agree. Better to store info in the array instead of a cell.